# Why does sh display an error when bash does not?

Tags: shell-script

Why does the following script display an "unexpected operator" message and fail when run with `sh`, but not with `bash`.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $UID -ne 0 ]
then
        echo "You must be root."
        exit 1
else
        echo "Open sesame."
        exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all shells define a variable `UID`. This is a bash and zsh feature only. In other shells, the `UID` variable is not defined, so your test command expands to `[ -ne 0 ]` which is a syntax error.

A portable way to obtain the user ID is with the [`id`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/id.html) utility.

```
if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then …
```

Comment: Another note is that quoting `"$UID"` would prevent the expansion from causing a syntax error.